# If condition to handle template.html with Ionic and angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

How can i config specific template.html by if condition in controller.js

```
if('posts.html') { 
    //do something
} else 
    if (home.html) {
        ///do somthing else
    }
```

please i read many article without any luck.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you trying to do different things according to different template?

If so, why don't you make each corresponding controller for them?

Comment: Maybe you right but i connect my ionic application with wordpress website through JSON API , and i have many category and i want to add to each category template.html  and its difficult ,so I believe there is another way to do that like this:                                                               `if (posts.html == true) { var postsApi =  $rootScope.url + 'posts?filter[category_name]=cook'} else if (home.html == true) 
{var postsApi =  $rootScope.url + 'posts?filter[category_name]=dessert' }`

Comment: I'm sorry. I still don't get what you're trying to achieve. Could you give me some more detail? Examples of what would actually happen would be nice.

Comment: I have about 6 var $var1 , $var2 ... , I need to add If condition which add to each page.html one of this variable , EX:  ` if (page1.html){$var1} else if (page2.html){$var2} else if(page3.html ){$var3} etc ` in controllers.js but i don't know how can i use template.html in if condition, must i use template.html == true or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

This is how we use in our project

templateUrl: (!isSmallScreen)?"InvoiceDetail/invoice-detail.html":"InvoiceDetail/Invoice-detailMobile.html"